# Unexpected output when printing std::string of my Get MAC Address function?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Working with VC++, when I obtain local system's MAC address it gives me a hex code. I need to convert this to a std::string so that I can use it else where in my code.
but I am not being able to get it properly.
I know I must be missing a very basic concept about strings in c++, please help me out here.

**Here is My COde :-**

```
void getMACAddr()
{
CCLOG("getMACAddr 1");
IP_ADAPTER_INFO *info = NULL, *pos;
DWORD size = 0;

GetAdaptersInfo(info, &size);

info = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(size);

GetAdaptersInfo(info, &size);
CCLOG("getMACAddr 2");

for (pos = info; pos != NULL; pos = pos->Next) 
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    CCLOG("getMACAddr 3");
    CCLOG("\n%s\n\t", pos->Description);
    CCLOG("HEX = :%2.2x", pos->Address[0]);
    ss << pos->Address[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < pos->AddressLength; i++)
    {
        CCLOG("HEX = :%2.2x", pos->Address[i]);
        ss << pos->Address[i];
    }
    std::string tS = ss.str();
    CCLOG("%s", tS.c_str());
}
free(info);


}
```

**Here is my output :-**

```
getMACAddr 1
'prog.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.dll'.Cannot find or open the PDB file.
getMACAddr 2
getMACAddr 3

Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)

HEX = :08
HEX = :3e
HEX = :8e
HEX = :aa
HEX = :37
HEX = :52
tS == >??7R
```

As you can see.

the last line of output("tS == >??7R") is strange.

what should I do to get entire Address in a single string ?

Comment: Since this is tagged with `cocos2d-x`, just a word of advice: `GetAdaptersInfo` is a Windows API function, and won't exist on mobile devices.

Comment: @Thomas : I know.  but my program is only for windows, not for mobile devices., so no worries about that

Comment: `08` unprintable, `3e` `>`, `8e aa` no glyph(`? ?`), `37` `7`, `52` `R`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IP_ADAPTER_INFO::Address` is an array of `BYTE`, so you probably want to convert the bytes to hex notation instead of stuffing them into a string as if they were characters.

Something like this:

```
#include <iomanip>

ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2);
for (int i = 0; i < pos->AddressLength; i++) {
  ss << (int) pos->Address[i];
}
std::string tS = ss.str();
```